# seeding private variable in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm testing a service in Nestjs like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
  private readonly products: Map<string, Product> = new Map();

  async create(product: Product): Promise<{ id: string; product: Product }> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let productAllowed: boolean;
      // do some magic
      // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
      productAllowed = true;
      if (!productAllowed) {
        reject(new NotAcceptableException('Such product exists'));
      }
      this.products.set('id', product);
      resolve({
        id: 'id',
        product,
      });
    });
  }

  async findOne(id: string): Promise<Product> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.products.has(id)) {
        reject(new NotAcceptableException('No such product exists'));
      }
      resolve(this.products.get(id));
    });
  }
}
```

I can test create() and it's ok.
but when testing findOne() I have a trouble:

I need a Product to exist in products Map so that I can find it by ID; but it's empty. so I need a way to somehow seed or mock it before calling findOne():

```
  describe('findOne()', () => {
    it('should return a product', async () => {
      const result: Product = {
        name: 'product',
        price: 100,
        category: 'junk',
      };

      expect(await service.findOne('id')).toStrictEqual(result);
    });

    it('should throw error on wrong id', async () => {
      const result = new NotAcceptableException('No such product found');
      expect(await service.findOne('not-id')).toThrowError(result);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Whatever you're doing with `productAllowed` is a really crappy idea.

Comment: I know, I added it temporarily; for example I'm gonna check if names are duplicated or sth to return an error instead of rewriting an existent product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're feeling uncomfortable because you think it's "wrong" to use the `create` function in the `findOne` unit test. Don't worry about it.

What are the point of unit tests? To ease your mind about your software performing the way you think it should. Unit tests aren't an academic exercise in creating units and testing them in isolation, they're a tool to help you ship stable software.

In short, there is nothing wrong with a test suite that looks like this:

```
  describe('productService', () => {
    it('should create a product', async () => { ... });

    it('should throw an error when creating a disallowed product', async () => { ... });

    it('should retrieve a product', async () => {
       // use create here, it's ok, relax....
       // if you really wanted to, do 2 assertions in here
       // one for the creation and one for the findOne and get rid of the first test
       const { id } = await service.create(...some product);
       const product = await service.findOne(id);
    });

    it('should throw an error when retreiving a product that doesnt exist', async () => { ... });
  });
```

Those 4 tests (3 if you combine `create` and `findOne`) test the entire functionality of your product service. Done, that's it.

If anything goes wrong, then either that test suite or your service needs updating - a failure will show up indicating, "hey dev - go look at product service and/or it's test suite" and you've achieved what you needed to achieve - the test suite and the service are both quite small (well done!), it won't take long to find the error.

Can't remember who said it:

> A suite of imperfectly written tests run often is far better than a suite of perfectly written tests run never

Comment: thanks, about the part it should throw an error on wrong id, how to check if that error I wanted is thrown?

Comment: @arianpress [rejects in jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#rejects)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ProductsService` become stateful, this is not a good thing.

In the current situation, you can use a bad trick to access to `products` map - In js, we do not have privates field:

```
(service as any).products = new Map([
        ["productId", product],
    ]);
```

Example: Your test case will become:

```
    it('should return a product', async () => {
      const result: Product = {
        name: 'product',
        price: 100,
        category: 'junk',
      };

      // this line
      (service as any).products = new Map([
         ["id", product],
      ]);

      expect(await service.findOne('id')).toStrictEqual(result);
    });
```

My recommendation is to use another service as a "cache" service and inject the service into `ProductsService` service.

Comment: So it's not okay for the products service to be stateful, but it is okay for the cache service to be stateful?

Comment: `cache service` as their name, you can write and read the "state", the behavior is different.

Comment: Fair point. This does make sense in a DI-style framework. Related: I hate it when Java developers try to build JS frameworks.

Comment: One further point, I'd give this answer an upvote if it demonstrated a proper DI style and how to test it using DI, rather than saying "here's how to grossly hack it".